# With Entity Framework Core Fluent API, how can I stop it creating an autoincrementing primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I tried this but it seems not to accept  `.ValueGeneratedNever();`

```
public class CardConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Card>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Card> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        builder.ToTable("CARDS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it on the property, not on the key.

```cs
public class CardConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Card>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Card> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        builder.ToTable("CARDS");
    }
}
```